# How to find remote login address from terminal

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, remote-access, scp

I use scp to copy files from a remote (Linux) computer to my local machine (Mac OS Mojave). I have "Remote Login" enabled on my Mac. In the "Sharing" section of System Preferences, where I enabled "Remote Login," an address is listed, which, when I'm on UCLA's campus for example, looks like this:

`my_name@wifi-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.host.ucla.edu`

This address (numbers x'ed and name removed) allows me to `ssh` into my Mac from the foreign computer and in particular to use `scp` to transfer files.

On the foreign machine, I use

`scp filename my_name@wifi-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.host.ucla.edu:~/Downloads`

and the file appears in my Mac's Downloads folder.

I would like to automate this process. The remote address seems to change frequently. How do I obtain my computer's address from the command line? Mac OS can clearly generate it, as it lists it in System Preferences.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try setting a static IP for your mac for this network? Does it still change your address?

Comment: @Teshan how would I set a static IP on a network?

Comment: System Prefs > Network. On Ethernet you can see where it says "Using DHCP", so you change that to DHCP with manual address. On Wifi it's inside the Advanced section, under TCP/IP. Note that fixing the address *may* lead to conflicts you will be unable to resolve, unless you can persuade the Uni to give you a fixed address from their side.

Comment: @Tetsujin this answers my question. If you post this as an "answer," I'll accept it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a workaround than a full answer to the question as asked, but after comments…

System Prefs > Network. On Ethernet you can see where it says "Using DHCP", so you change that to DHCP with manual address. On Wifi it's inside the Advanced section, under TCP/IP.

Note that fixing the address may lead to conflicts you will be unable to resolve, unless you can persuade the Uni to give you a fixed address from their side.